# Identify a hollywood 2000's romance genre movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

**Genre** : Romance + Thriller (Thriller, in the sense there is no crime nor shooting)

**Actors** : Male part is played by someone similar in age/appearance to Ryan Reynolds/Gosling. Female protagonist, not sure. There is a 3rd actress who is 'not much shown in scenes' but plays a *very important* role in this movie.

**Date** : A movie probably in the timeline 2003 - 2010. Its a 2000s movie anyway.

**Story**: I faintly remember it and there are 2 possible plots and one of them is right:

Plot 1: The hero and heroine meet each other and fall in love and due to some turn of events get separated geographically and are remaining apart. In the course of the movie they are in their run to meet each other.

Plot2: The hero and heroine have not met each other in person but knows about each other by some form of indirect communication. In the course of the movie they are in their run to meet each other.

Be it Plot1 or Plot2, the 3rd female actor I mentioned about is a friend of the female lover. She knows about the 2 lovers and their relationship. During the course of the movie she acts to keep them separated/meeting from each other. But this intention of hers is only revealed at the end of the movie and is the "suspense". It turns out that it was only because this 3rd female character had a crush on the male protagonist. The 3rd character herself confesses about all what she had done to keep them from meeting each other. But eventually both the lovers are united.

Comment: @ovaherenow Thanks for response but sadly 'My best friend's wedding' is not the movie. The movie inquired does not have Julia R or 'wedding scene'.

Comment: My first thought was that you were conflating My Best Friends Wedding with Serendipity

Answer (score 7):

I found it. The movie is [Wicker Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0324554/).

I remember seeing the hero in a movie with Morgan Freeman and Bruce Willis. I googled both the names together and bumped into [Lucky Number Slevin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425210/) and searched the cast to find out the hero's name. Then from imdb I searched his movie list and got it :) I had seen this movie earlier. The 3rd character I was mentioning about is played by 'Rose Byrne'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ["My Best Friend's Wedding"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119738/) with Julia Roberts?

As per IMDB:

> When a woman's long-time friend says he's engaged, she realizes she
>   loves him herself... and sets out to get him, with only days before
>   the wedding.

It kind of sounds like the description above.